# Generate single XML file based on data from two tables or more

Tags: php, mysql, html, xml

[image: diagram]

There are two tables, which have a relationship(one-to-many). There are `Meals` table which contains values such as Breakfast(`id: 1`), Brunch(`id: 2`), Lunch(`id: 3`), Tea(`id: 4`), Dinner(`id: 5`) and Supper(`id: 6`). Then there are `Foods` table which contains various foods and each food(i.e. Hamburger) is linked to a particular type of meal(i.e. Lunch) via a foreign key. So, the row `idfood: 12; idmeal: 3; foodname: "Hamburger"` would mean that `"Hamburger"` is of `Lunch` meal type.

I created an XML generator file which pulls the contents of the whole `Food` table into an XML file. Problem is I want to translate `idmeal` foreign key values into actual meal names from the `Meal` table for each food element inside XML.

The simple way would be to include the foreign key number from `Food` table, but that would be too cryptic(i.e. Hamburger is eaten during 3 time). Instead I wanted to make it so based on whatever the foreign key number is - the XML would insert the right value from the `Meals` tables(`mealname`) into that one XML file with foods so that I could print something like "Hamburger is eaten during Lunch time".

GenerateXML.php:

```
<?php
require("includes/credentials.php");

$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $doc->createElement("foods");
$parnode = $doc->appendChild($node);

$connection=mysql_connect($host, $usr, $pass);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM food";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

  $node = $doc->createElement("food");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);

  $newnode->setAttribute("idfood", $row['idfood']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("idmeal", $row['idmeal']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("foodname", $row['foodname']);
}

echo $xmlfile = $doc->saveXML();

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

join the tables in your query to make use of your FK relationship.

```
Select meals.mealname, food.foodname from food join meals on (food.mealid = meals.mealid)
```